# Subdomain Wp-Admin Not Found

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I enabled the MultiSite option using the instructions on the WordPress site (`` `mandeltech.com), and now I am trying to create a subsdomain for WooCommerce ( ``shop.mandeltech.com`). I created the subdomain with cPanel, and then added it to my site through My Sites --> Network Admin --> Sites --> Add Site menu. All of the settings worked, except I can't access the dashboard.

Using the dashboard link from the My Sites menu, I go to `http://shop.mandeltech.com/wp-admin/`. This gives me a 404 Error, because that page does not exist. Through the cPanel file manager, the `shop` directory under `public_html` only has a `cgi-bin` folder. This makes sense, as I haven't specifically added anything.

However, I'm not sure where to go from here. I want both `shop.mandeltech.com` and `mandeltech.com` to share the same WP installation and database, but I can't access the WP-Admin page yet. Do I have to install WordPress for this subdirectory? This would create another installation, so it doesn't seem like the correct way to go. So, how can I allow this subdomain to have the same WP installation but also access its dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-can-i-install-subdomains-within-wordpress-multi-site), perhaps it will be useful.

Comment: @dalbaeb I've read through it and the only thing I haven't done is wildcard DNS (because I won't need this). I'm just having trouble accessing the WP-Admin panel for the new shop page, simply because the `wp-admin` folder doesn't exist in `public_html/shop`.

Comment: Currently I made a symbolic link to my main wp-admin, using SSH. This seemed to have worked, but I don't think this is how it should actually be done.

Answer (score 0):

Another WP install is not needed; that would defeat the whole idea of multisite. I am not sure about multisite sub-folder network, but at least in a sub-domain network, whose wp-config has `define ('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true)`, you can think of WP as a gateway to all sub-domains, whose doc roots must all point to the main WP install directory. WP will take it from there and send content based on the requested domain name.

So ... instead of `path/public_html/shop`, point shop.mandeltech.com to the same path as mandeltech.com, eg. `path/public_html`. In other words, where the entry point index.php of the main install of WP resides.